# Bottle conditioned brew has condensation

Tags: bottle-conditioning

Is condensation okay in a finished bottle conditioned homebrew? It has been two weeks and I just tested one, it tasted fine but I am curious if that is ok. Also, some of the bottles have some white stuff floating on the top... are those okay to drink?

Comment: This is not really an answer, but I can think of a few sources of white floaties: krausen residue from fermentation in the bottle, bacterial infection, wild yeast infection.

Comment: Most things that grow in beer won't kill you. But they will taste bad and may give you gastrointestinal discomfort. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condensation is fine.  You have a liquid at one temp and the exterior can experience a temp swing causing condensation.  It has nothing to do with the beer, its just science.

Without knowing your process its hard to guess at what the white floaties may or may not be.

Answer (score 0):

What did you condition with?  I've heard some of the carb tabs can leave white particles.  If you've used a sugar water mixture, I wonder if this could be an infection of sorts.
Did you taste anything off in your sample?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what it was that I conditioned with. It came with the kit I had. It was too fine to be regular sugar though. as for the taste, sadly this is my first batch, I don't know what "off" means.

Comment: Probably dextrose A.K.A corn sugar. You'd know "off" if you tasted it.

Comment: haha, makes sense. It does not have any off tastes then.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the 'floaties' twice. If I lager over a long period, even in winter, they occur. I researched it and just rack the beer of from below. They won't affect the taste, but will turn into a full-blown infection if left for too long; pretty much like any beer will, even without floaties.